# What's the difference between the Allocators of a NativeArray?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, job-scheduling, unity-burst

When should I use which value (`None`, `Invalid`, `Temp`, `TempJob`, `Persistent`, `FirstUserIndex`, `AudioKernal`)

How does each `Allocator` affect allocation and the lifespan of the `NativeArray` in implementation?

I can't figure out how the lifespans/implementations differ for each `Allocator` value when instantiating a `NativeArray`. I've checked the docs and IntelliSense to no avail, besides being shown which `Enum` values are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### In-depth look at allocators:
>
> https://www.jacksondunstan.com/articles/5406

## `Allocator.Temp`

Offers fastest allocation time. [Is valid for a single frame](https://www.jacksondunstan.com/articles/5446). No need to call `Dispose()`.
Can't be assigned to field of a job struct (because job's lifetime can be over 1 frame) but can be allocated by a job execution code.

```cs
struct AJob : IJob
{
    void IJob.Execute ()
    {
        var tempArray = new NativeArray<int>( 128 , Allocator.Temp );
        for( int i=0 ; i<tempArray.Length ; i++ )
        {
            /* does something useful with it */
        }
        // tempArray.Dispose() call is optional as Temp will deallocate automagically
    }
}
```

## `Allocator.TempJob`

Fast, temporary allocations for job struct fields.

```cs
public class LetsScheduleAJob : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int[] _inputs = new int[]{ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 };
    public JobHandle Dependency;
    void Update ()
    {
        Dependency.Complete();// makes sure previously-scheduled job is completed by now

        var temporaryData = new NativeArray<int>( _inputs , Allocator.TempJob );
        Dependency = new SumUpJob{
            NumbersToSumUp = temporaryData ,
        }.Schedule();
        temporaryData.Dispose( Dependency );// deallocates on job completion
    }
}

struct SumUpJob : IJob
{
    public NativeArray<int> NumbersToSumUp;
    void IJob.Execute ()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for( int i=0 ; i<NumbersToSumUp.Length ; i++ )
            sum += NumbersToSumUp[i];
        Debug.Log($"sum: {sum}");
    }
}
```

## `Allocator.Persistent`

Slow allocation. No lifetime restrictions. Must call `Dispose()` to free (memory leak otherwise). Ideal for data that needs to always exist for a system to function.

```cs
public class LetsScheduleAJob : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int[] _inputs = new int[]{ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 };
    NativeArray<int> _data;
    public JobHandle Dependency;
    void Awake ()
    {
        _data = new NativeArray<int>( _inputs.Length , Allocator.Persistent );
        _data.CopyFrom( _inputs );
    }
    void OnDestroy ()
    {
        Dependency.Complete();
        if( _data.IsCreated ) _data.Dispose();// I (class) allocated this array so (only) I Dispose it
    }
    void Update ()
    {
        Dependency.Complete();// makes sure previously-scheduled job is completed by now

        _data.CopyFrom( _inputs );

        Dependency = new SumUpJob{
            NumbersToSumUp = _data ,
        }.Schedule();
    }
}
```

## `Allocator.None`

`Allocator.None` is for these rare cases where you need to say "no allocation happened here" to create a valid `NativeArray` of which lifetime is decided elsewhere. For example, to access managed memory as if it is just another `NativeArray`:

```cs
void* ptr = UnsafeUtility.PinGCArrayAndGetDataAddress(managedArray, out gcHandle);
var nativeArray = NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.ConvertExistingDataToNativeArray<T>(ptr, managedArray.Length, Allocator.None);
```

source: https://gist.github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/812e152f95e38cc13c44e5040c5739bc

## `Invalid`

Signals allocation failure. Don't use.

## `FirstUserIndex`

No idea. Don't use.

> @derHugo wrote:
> `FirstUserIndex` is just another check index, you can define custom allocators (see [AllocatorManager.Register](https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.collections@1.2/api/Unity.Collections.AllocatorManager.html#Unity_Collections_AllocatorManager_Register__1___0__)), you wouldn't pass this one in yourself though, this is internally handled

## `AudioKernel`

No idea. Don't use.

> @derHugo wrote:
> Seems to be very use case specific for jobs related to the [DOTS DSPGraph](https://forum.unity.com/threads/dots-audio-discussion.651982/page-2)

Comment: `Invalid` is indeed for internal usage and should not be used, `FirstUserIndex` is just another check index, you can define custom allocators (see [`AllocatorManager.Register`](https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.collections@1.2/api/Unity.Collections.AllocatorManager.html#Unity_Collections_AllocatorManager_Register__1___0__)), you wouldn't pass this one in yourself though, this is internally handled, and `AudioKernel` seems to be very use case specific for jobs related to the [DOTS DSPGraph](https://forum.unity.com/threads/dots-audio-discussion.651982/page-2)

Comment: The `NativeArray` contuctor calls `Allocate` which (if checks are enabled) calls `CheckAllocateArguments` which literally says `if (allocator <= Allocator.None)
        throw new ArgumentException("Allocator must be Temp, TempJob or Persistent", nameof (allocator));
      if (allocator >= Allocator.FirstUserIndex)
        throw new ArgumentException("Use CollectionHelper.CreateNativeArray for custom allocator", nameof (allocator));`